# Remove empty form functions

Tags: qt

I have generated many unused **on_** events in my form code like:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Is there any way automatically remove them?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, explain what it means to eliminate?

Comment: I think you are reffering to slots created automatically by QtCreator from the designer (e.g. when double clicking on a pushButton). I'm afraid there isn't a refactoring function to remove empty methods (and it would be pretty dangerous actually).

Comment: Qt Creator can only create slots. Unused slots need to be removed in the `.h/.hpp` and `.cpp` file manually.

Comment: the creation of those slots is not automatic, you had to do it through Qt Designer, so I see it silly to erase them, it's better not to create them. :D